# sumList predicate needs to check to see if their Sum is equal to the sum of all the elements in the list

Tags: prolog

I am implementing a method that when given `Sum` and a `List`. It will check to see that if you add the elements in the list, their sum is equal to the Sum given. Here is what I am trying to do thus far, but I am pretty sure it is wrong... I'm not really sure how to think about it.

```
  sumList([],0).
  sumList([X|Xrest], Sum) :-
     sumList[Xrest, Sum1),
     Sum is X + Sum1.
```

Could you give me a point in the right direction or at least let me know how to try to think about the problem?

Comment: Your code is almost ok. Just replace the `[` in `sumList[XRest` with `(`, that is `sumList(Xrest, Sum1)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all good with you code, except bracket in `sumList[Xrest, Sum1)`.

So, this works pretty well in my `swipl`:

```
  sumList([],0).
  sumList([X|Xrest], Sum) :-
     sumList(Xrest, Sum1),
     Sum is X + Sum1.

?- sumList([1,2,3],X).
X = 6.
```